# Mounting a projector underneath a soffit containing ductwork

Tags: mounting, ducts, hanging, projector, project-planning

I’m looking to install a projector in my basement and the most ideal configuration would be to mount it to the ceiling with a ceiling mount. However, the “sweet spot” location for hanging (in considering distance to the projector screen) falls underneath a bulkhead that houses AC and heating ductwork, and I don’t detect any beams with my stud finder.

I obviously don’t want to mount directly into the ductwork for many reasons (vibration, projector misalignment due to changing temperatures expanding/contracting, air leaks, etc.).

What are some other options? The projector is only 8 lbs., so can I use construction adhesive (like liquid nails) to adhere a piece of wood onto the drywall, and then mount the projector into the wood? The projector mount includes 2.5” lag bolts for mounting...

I’ve also considered a projector shelf on the back wall but given the distance to the screen, the projector lens should be 28.24” from the back wall - so that would be a very deep (and perhaps custom built) shelf.

Here’s a picture of the area. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The drywall of the bulkhead has to be screwed in to something.  There **is** framing in there.  Instead of a stud locator, try a strong magnet to locate the drywall screws.

Comment: The zoom should be able to handle a measly extra foot of throw. Get it atop a bookcase or something before you decide to start drilling holes. Ideally you set it low so you don't have to keystone the crap out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be some sort of framing around the ductwork although I would bet it's just a 1x2 board and not suitable for lag bolts.

I would suggest to do the shelf idea or mount it from the ceiling.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have to go with the shelf option as the real ceiling is too far forward.